# One-point correlation function of any quasi-primary operator is zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

How do I show the following:

> In a general CFT (with no boundary), the one-point correlation function of any primary operator $A_Δ$ is $0$ (unless we are talking about the identity operator): $$<A_Δ(x)>=0~?$$

Also (may be somewhat related due the transformation properties) how can I show that the vacuum expectation value of a Lorentz covariant vector is zero?

Comment: Invariance under translation implies that the one-point function is constant. But then covariance under scale transformations implies either that it is zero, or that the scaling dimension of the operator is zero. The only operator with scaling dimension zero is the identity.

Comment: @M. Jo: Good answer, but in the absence of further assumptions nothing forces an operator of dimension zero to be the identity. And actually nothing forces an identity operator to exist.

Comment: @SylvainRibault If the theory is unitary, there is a lower bound on the scaling dimension of operators and no operator of scaling dimension zero is allowed, except for the identity.
If the theory is not unitary, it's a different story...